# How to Print parsed JSON data in HTML page in a table

Tags: javascript, html

I have accessed the JSON data through web service call and parsed the JSON data. I would like to know how to print that JSON data in HTML table???

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<title>File Download</title>
<script type="text/javascript" src="Scripts/jquery-1.7.2.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">

    function jsonparser1() {
        $.ajax({
            type: "GET",
            crossDomain: true,
            url: "http://10.211.2.219:8080/JerseyWebService/rest/sample/files",
            dataType: "jsonp",
            success: function (res) {
                $.each(res['data'], function (i, row) {
                    var ftime = row['time'];
                    var fname = row['name'];
                    var fhref = row['href'];

                    document.myform.???????????????=ftime;
                    ??????????????????????????????????????
                    ??????????????????????????????????????  
                })
            },

            error: function (xml) {
                alert(xml.status + ' ' + xml.statusText);
            }
        });
    }        
</script>    
</head>
<body>
<form name="myform">
    <input type="button" name="clickme" value="Click here to display the details of the files" onclick=jsonparser1() />
    ??????????????????????????????????????????
    ??????????????????????????????????????????     
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

The JSON data i am using is:

```
{"data":[{"id":13,"time":"02-08-2012 3:24:45 PM","name":"jersey-multipart-1.0.3.144640.jar","href":"file://chndlf716168/TempUp/1343901285087-FileName-jersey-multipart-1.0.3.144640.jar"},{"id":14,"time":"02-08-2012 3:36:0 PM","name":"icloud_hero.png.png","href":"file://chndlf716168/TempUp/1343901960304-FileName-icloud_hero.png.png"}],"code":true}
```

I would like to display the time,name and href attributes in a table format. The href should be in anchor tag. If more number of data are appended into JSON file means, the table should be flexible to change. First step is that i have to display the details in table format.

Anybody please helpout in this thing... Thanks in advance...

Comment: http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.getJSON/ use this tutorial

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hope this helps:

```
$("document").ready(function() {
    $.getJSON("http://localhost:1909/encoders", function(data) {

        $("#div-my-table").text("<table>");

        $.each(data, function(i, item) {
            $("#div-my-table").append("<tr><td>" + item.EncoderName +"</td><td>" + item.EncoderStatus + "</td></tr>");
        });

        $("#div-my-table").append("</table>");

    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this out

```
var output = "<table>";
    $.each(res['data'], function (i, row) {                     
        var ftime = row['time'];                     
        var fname = row['name'];                     
        var fhref = row['href'];
        output+="<tr><td>VARIABLE VALUE</td></tr>";
        })
output += "</table>";
```

When the outpur variable is ready with the content. Print it in the desire location.

Comment: @thenetimp I know, if the coder does not have any idea, how to show the variable value in the html format, then I have to give some easy idea rather then complex jquery method notations.

Answer (score 0):

This is basic jquery  in your each loop do this.

```
$row = $('<tr></tr>');
$row.append('<td>' + somedata + '</td>');
// repeat the above line for each data item
$('#mytable).append($row);
```

In your HTML create `<table id="mytable"></table>`